# Primitive of continuous function [Zorich's book]

Tags: real-analysis, integration

[image]

Hello! This is an excerpt form Zorich's book (on page 361) and I am slightly confused. Firstly he gives the definition of *generalized primitive*. There is a  slight difference between *primitive* and *generalized primitive*.

The Theorem 1' states that any primitive of $f$ on $[a,b]$ has the form $(6.43)$. I was wondering which primitive he means when he write "any primitive of $f$"? Usual primitive or generalized primitive? Judging by the proof of the theorem I have an impression that he means usual primitive.

Thanks a lot for your answer!

**EDIT:** And I guess there is a small mistake in the proof (he says that $\mathcal{F}(x)-F(x)$ is constant on each of the finite number of intervals into which the discontinuities of $f$ divide the closed interval $[a,b]$). We should divide the closed interval $[a,b]$ into finitely many taking points where $f$ is not continuous and ALSO the points where $\mathcal{F}'(x)\neq f(x)$.

Comment: Theorem 1' is about generalized primitive.

Comment: At points of continuity you will have $\mathcal{F} '(x) =f(x) $.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh, so my edit is wrong?

Comment: @ParamanandSingh, I am slightly confused why at points of continuity we have $\mathcal{F}'(x)=f(x)$? Could you explain this please?

Comment: @Reveillark, that is right for function $F:[a,b]\to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $F(x)=\int_{a}^{x}f(t)dt$. However, Paramanand Singh claimed that it is true for any generalized primitive $\mathcal{F}$. Do you see the difference?

Comment: Oh I see, I misread things, my apologies. I'll think harder about it.

Comment: If we have $F, f$ continuous on $[a, b] $ and $F'=f$ except possibly at $c\in[a, b] $ then we also have $F'(c) =f(c) $. Why? Use mean value theorem.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh, What do you mean by $F$ here? Any generalized primitive or $F(x)=\int_{a}^{x}f(t)dt$? Also, I do not see how you apply MVT here. It would be better if you can demonstrate it. Can you write it as an answer?

Comment: Well $F$ is any function which satisfies $F'=f$ except possibly at $c$. So it is a generalized primitive of $f$. The thing is if $f$ is continuous then even at the exceptional point you have $F'=f$.

Comment: You should just note that $(F(c+h) - F(c)) /h=F'(\xi) =f(\xi) $ where $\xi$ is between $c$ and $c+h$. If $h\to 0$ then $\xi\to c$ and $f(\xi) \to f(c) $. So we have $F'(c) =f(c) $.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh, Just to be sure that I am understanding everything in a correct way. Suppose that $F(x)=\int_{a}^{x}f(t)dt$ and $G(x)$ is any other generalized primitive of $f$ on $[a,b]$. Suppose that $\{\xi_1,\dots,\xi_N\}$ are the points where $f$ is discontinuous. Consider interval $\Delta_i=(\xi_i,\xi_{i+1})$. First of all, we see that $F'(x)=f(x)$ on $\Delta_i$. Let's  prove that $G'(x)=f(x)$ on $\Delta_i$.

Comment: Take any point $c\in \Delta_i$ and $h>0$ so small that $G'(x)=f(x)$ on $(c,c+h)$ (it is possible because $G'(x)=f(x)$ on $[a,b]$ except for finitely many points). Then by MVT we have: $\frac{G(c+h)-G(c)}{h}=G'(r)\equiv f(r)$ for $r\in (c,c+h)$. Taking $h\to 0$ and since $f$ is continuous on $\Delta_i$ we see that $G'(c)=f(c)$. Does it look correct?

Comment: Yes, it is correct! +1 for the question.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh, thanks a lot for your help! I remember you helped me many times and your answers usually are really clear! Thanks a lot for patience!

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your edit, if $f$ is continuous at $x$, then $\mathcal F'(x)=f(x)$, so there is no need for an additional subdivision. Or, rather, we know this once we've proved the theorem. So you technically need to do the additional subdivision to carry out the argument (at least in this form), but then the result tells you that in fact $F'(x)=f(x)$ at any point of continuity of $f$ for a general $\mathcal F$.

The proof goes through if you replace every instance of "primitive" by "generalized primitive", since the latter are defined to be continuous on $[a,b]$, so $\mathcal F-F$ is a continuous function on $[a,b]$ that takes finitely many values, hence is constant by the Intermediate Value Theorem.

Comment: Hmm. So you mean if $f$ is continuous at $x$, then $\mathcal{F}'(x)=f(x)$ for any generalized primitive $\mathcal{F}$ of $f$?

Comment: Since you edited your post I am really confused now. May I ask you question please?

Comment: @ZFR Upon further reflection, I think you're correct in that the additional subdivision is needed. But, once the theorem if proven, you know that any generalized primitive $F$ differs from $\mathcal F$ by a constant, hence must satisfy $F'(x)=f(x)$ whenever $f$ is continuous at $x$. Does this help?

Comment: Technically I think we need to add points where $f(x)$ is discontinuous and also points where $\mathcal{F}'(x)=f(x)$ fails. Then using these points we need to subdivide our interval and on each such interval $F(x)-\mathcal{F}(x)$ is constant. Since $\mathcal{F}(x)-F(x)$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ then $\mathcal{F}-F=const$ on $[a,b]$. Hence any GENERALIZED primitive of $f$ on $[a,b]$ looks like $\int_{a}^{x}f(t)dt+c$.

Comment: @ZFR Correct. This is a kind of "self-strengthening" statement. You add the points to run your proof. Then, you realize that the thing you just proved actually tells you that you didn't need to add these points, but you have no way of knowing this before proving the theorem (unless, of course, you give a different proof).

Comment: Yeah but in order to make the proof formally correct we need to add two set of points.

Comment: @ZFR Yes, indeed.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think you need to add points for $f(x)$ at discontinuous points. And I will try to paraphrase Zorich's proof to explain why.

Thm1' states the existence of generalized primitive of f and then its uniqueness. **Existence**: $F(x) = \int_{a}^{x} f(t) dt$ exists because $f \in \mathcal{R}[a, b]$. And what's more, (in the latter discussion on the top of p.361), we know this $F(x)$ is continuous (whatever f has discontinuous points or not).
**Uniqueness**: Assume there is another $\mathcal{F}(x)$ be the generalized primitive of $f$, then $\mathcal{F}(x)$ is also continuous. By the facts that the difference of two continuous functions is also continuous, we know $P(x) = \mathcal{F}(x) - F(x)$ is continuous. And at the continuous points of $f$, $P(x) = c$ (because $P^{'}(x) = 0$). Then by continuity, we know at discontinuity $x_{0}$, $P(x_{0}) = \lim_{x \rightarrow x_{0}} P(x) = c$.

As for me, I do not see why you need mean value thoeory as the comment under your original question.

Moreover, I am also struggling with Zorich and yesterday I also have some questions about the generalized primitive, but my questions are different from your's. Maybe latter I will post my question and hope you have the answer.

Comment: After learning improper integration, there is more concentration for the continuity of primitives but not the f(x).