# A question about generalized primitive in Zorich's book

Tags: integration, analysis

Zorich proves that even if $f(x)$ has **finitely many** dicontinuous points, $f(x)$ can have a generalized primitive. But I contrast this definition with Riemann integrable which says that for an interval $g(x)$ is intergrable if the discontinuities of $g(x)$ is measure zero. And that means even if $g(x)$ has **infinitely many** discontinuities, $g(x)$ is integrable.

So my question is: If $f(x)$ has **infinitely many** discontinuities, can $f(x)$ have generalized primitives? And if it can't, why? please give an counterexample.

(I think countably many discontinuities does not influence $f$'s generalized primitive, and the proof is similar to Zorich's thm1'. But why Zorich only give a week version of finitely many exception points?)

*Sorry, I forgot the give the source of this page, p.362, Zorich, Mathematical Analysis I, 2nd edition.*

[image: Zorich's generalized primitive in p.362, Mathematical Analysis I, 2nd edition]

Comment: As for the definition of generalized primitive and discussion about it, go to  https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4282655